# Pass specific Form Input to Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a forum where I use multiple forms on one page with the same ID. So when I try to get the input through `document.getElementById("#id").val` it will always select the first form on the website. I generate these forms so I can't change the IDs separately.

So what I tried to do is pass parameters to the jQuery function like this:

```php
echo '<form id="delete-form" method="POST" action="javascript:deleteComment(comment_id_java.val, category_id_java.val, category_java.val)">';
echo '<input id="comment_id_java" type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$result_row['comment_id'].'">';
echo '<input id="category_id_java" type="hidden" name="urlid" value="'.$_GET['id'].'">';
echo '<input id="category_java" type="hidden" name="category" value="'.$_GET['category'].'">';
echo '<input id="delete-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="X">';
echo '</form>';

function deleteComment(comment_id_java, category_id_java, category_java){


    //Don't worry about this part, this works for sure I tested it.
    $.post("delete-comment.php", {
        id: comment_id,
        urlid: category_id,
        category: s_category
    });

    $("#comment-container").load("load-comments.php", {category:s_category, id:category_id});

}
```

This doesn't seem to work though because I keep getting `variable undefined` error.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the actual HTML code:

```html
<div id="comment-container">
  <div class="post-section">
    <div class="post-user-section">
      <h4>fiddel</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(70,70,70);">User</h4>
      <img src="Images/profile-picture.png">
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">18-05-22</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">Reputation: 0</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body-section-wide">
      <h5>Welcome User,
        <br>
        <br>This is the Announcement Section where we post any types of news!
      </h5>
    </div>
    <form id="vote-form" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="17"><input id="upvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128897;"><input id="downvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128899;"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="post-section">
    <div class="post-user-section">
      <h4>fiddel</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(70,70,70);">User</h4>
      <img src="Images/profile-picture.png">
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">18-05-24</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">Reputation: 0</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body-section-wide">
      <h5>ddadas</h5>
    </div>
    <form id="vote-form" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="21"><input id="upvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128897;"><input id="downvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128899;"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="post-section">
    <div class="post-user-section">
      <h4>fiddel</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(70,70,70);">User</h4>
      <img src="Images/profile-picture.png">
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">18-05-25</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">Reputation: 0</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body-section-wide">
      <h5>Why is this not locked LOL</h5>
    </div>
    <form id="vote-form" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="33"><input id="upvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128897;"><input id="downvote-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&#128899;"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="post-section">
    <div class="post-user-section">
      <h4>JasonB</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(255,23,41);">Owner</h4>
      <img src="Images/profile-picture.png">
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">18-05-29</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">Reputation: 0</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body-section">
      <h5>fdfsd</h5>
    </div>
    <form id="delete-form" method="POST" action="javascript:deleteComment(comment_id_java.value, category_id_java.value, category_java.value)"><input id="comment_id_java" type="hidden" name="id" value="83"><input id="category_id_java" type="hidden" name="urlid" value="17"><input id="category_java" type="hidden" name="category" value="announcements"><input id="delete-button" type="submit"
        name="submit" value="X"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="post-section">
    <div class="post-user-section">
      <h4>JasonB</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(255,23,41);">Owner</h4>
      <img src="Images/profile-picture.png">
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">18-05-29</h4>
      <h4 style="color:rgb(180,180,180);">Reputation: 0</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body-section">
      <h5>asasf</h5>
    </div>
    <form id="delete-form" method="POST" action="javascript:deleteComment(comment_id_java.value, category_id_java.value, category_java.value)"><input id="comment_id_java" type="hidden" name="id" value="84"><input id="category_id_java" type="hidden" name="urlid" value="17"><input id="category_java" type="hidden" name="category" value="announcements"><input id="delete-button" type="submit"
        name="submit" value="X"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us the actual HTML displayed on your page?

Comment: You should only have one unique id.

Comment: But you could get all the forms: `var forms = document.querySelector("form");` Then you can iterate over them.

Comment: How would I check what form it comes from?

Comment: This is not the *actual* HTML, this is PHP....

Comment: If I change it to a class. How do I then check what form it comes from?

Comment: @Radmation, Indeed you're right, my apologies. But he already has unique id's.

Comment: I would not wrap each comment with its own form. I would wrap all comments with one form and pass the id of the comment to be deleted.

Comment: I added the actual html now, sorry about that

Comment: You also could put the comment id as part of the id of the form. Example: `echo '<form id="delete-form-{$result_row['comment_id']}"`

Comment: Oh good Idea! I'll try to add it and i'll let you know how it went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to remove the deleted comments from the DOM after it has been deleted in the DB and because all your delete forms have the same id - you are unsure which one to remove from the DOM.

I would honeslty only have one `<form>` tag on my page wrapping everything that it needs too. And on the output you could do something like:

```
echo "<div id="comment-id-".$result_row['comment_id']."">Comment Here</div>
```

Then you will know how to reference the comment when you need to remove it.

```
document.getElementById("comment-id-<?php echo $result_row['comment_id']; ?>").style.display = "none";
```

The above code isn't perfect and likely has syntax errors but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @JasonGreb Glad I could help! Do you mind accepting the answer so this can be closed? Thanks!!

Comment: @JasonGreb Consider upvoting / accepting his answer for future reference.

Comment: I can only accept your answer, I can't upvote yet because I have less than 15 rep. :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you wish to select all `form`s you should use classes instead. remember you can always use more than one class per item. In the other hand, ids are unique and it would not be very easy to select all of them with JavaScript.

For example, you could add the class `form` to the `<form>` tags you want to select. I have provided the HTML code below (in PHP).

```php
echo '<form id="form delete-form" method="POST" action="javascript:deleteComment(comment_id_java.val, category_id_java.val, category_java.val)">';
echo '<input id="comment_id_java" type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $result_row['comment_id'] . '">';
echo '<input id="category_id_java" type="hidden" name="urlid" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '">';
echo '<input id="category_java" type="hidden" name="category" value="' . $_GET['category'] . '">';
echo '<input id="delete-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="X">';
echo '</form>';
```

Then in JavaScript, you can use the document method `.querySelectorAll` which allows you to select all elements that match the given selector. In your case use `document.querySelectorAll('.form')`. This will return an array of HTML elements.

Comment: This is not quiet what I was looking because I cannot distinguish what form was submitted but thank you anyway!